# improving accuracy for sample skewness and kurtosis under Student's t distribution with low degrees of freedom

Tags: simulation, monte-carlo, moments, t-distribution

There is no skewness in Student's t distribution. Given the degrees of freedom, the kurtosis estimator is given by $\frac{6}{\nu - 4}$. However, when sampling form a t-distribution with low degrees of freedom, there is significant estimation error in the sample estimates of skewness and kurtosis. Are there any methods for improving accuracy/(reducing bias) for sample skewness and kurtosis estimates when simulating data from a t-distribution with low degrees of freedom without increasing the sample size. Any Monte Carlo methods?

Comment: Since sample skewness and kurtosis are just statistics, it isn't evident what you mean by "accuracy."  Could you explain what this means in an edit to the question?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "the kurtosis estimator is given by $\frac{6}{\nu-4}$", presumably this isn't how you intend to estimate the kurtosis from the sample? Are you really saying that you want to produce simulated data whose kurtosis and skewness is closer to their theoretical values? Or are you saying that you want to estimate these statistics better from your sample?

Comment: I want to produce simulated data whose kurtosis and skewness is closer to their theoretical values without increasing my sample size. If my sample size was infinite then sample kurtosis must approach the asymptotic value. However, this does not happen and there is estimation error. Which is more pronounced if I sample from a t-distribution with low degrees of freedom.

Comment: "*I want to produce simulated data whose kurtosis and skewness is closer to their theoretical values without increasing my sample size*" -- Well, sure -- as long as you don't care about having a random sample from a t-distribution -- you can get the skewness and kurtosis as close as you want.

Comment: It dosen't work that well for low degrees of freedom and sample size around 100. It improves if I increase the sample size to 1000.